# Why when using self-sizing cells in iOS 8 does the constraint to the bottom of the cell have to be "greater than/equal" or use vertical hugging?

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios8

I'm trying to use Auto Layout to take advantage of the self-sizing `UITableViewCell`s.

I have one `UILabel` at the top of the cell and another beneath it. I set the top constraints to be pinned to the top, left and right, and the bottom to be pinned to the top left and right of the upper label.

Now as I go to set the bottom label's final constraint (its distance from the bottom) I set it to 10pt from the bottom of the cell. However this sparks a bunch of Auto Layout complaints. It says I have to make one of the labels have a higher vertical hugging priority. Why is this?

And in the WWDC video, the engineer sets the bottom one to be greater than or equal, instead of just equal. This seems like a poor solution at least in my case, because I never want it to be greater than what I set.

Answer (score 2):

The IB issue you are seeing is due to the fact that the content that you currently have in the labels and all your constraints doesn't fit the UITableViewCell height (it doesn't autosize in IB yet). The autosizing happens at runtime, and setting it to greater than or equal is fine as the code autosizing will find the smallest size that acceptably fits all your content.